# Spring Boot doesn't use custom deserializer for ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to setup my spring boot configuration to use my custom **serializer** and **deserializer.**

**Deserializer code**

```
public class CustomZonedDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        TextNode node = (TextNode) oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        String dateString = node.textValue();
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, CustomZonedDateTimeSerializer.formatter);
    }

@Override
public Class<?> handledType() {
    return ZonedDateTime.class;
}
```

}

**Serializer code**

```
public class CustomZonedDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public Class<ZonedDateTime> handledType() {
        return ZonedDateTime.class;
    }

    public final static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

    @Override
    public void serialize(ZonedDateTime date, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final String dateString = date.format(formatter);
        generator.writeString(dateString);

    }

}
```

**This my configuration:**

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder;

    @PostConstruct
    public void configureJackson() {

        final CustomZonedDateTimeSerializer serializer = new CustomZonedDateTimeSerializer();
        jacksonBuilder.serializers(serializer);

        final CustomZonedDateTimeDeserializer deserializer = new CustomZonedDateTimeDeserializer();
        jacksonBuilder.deserializers(deserializer);
    }

}
```

**I am creating a REST API so I have this in my controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "date", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
@ApiOperation(value = "", notes = "")
public ResponseWrapper<String> testDATE(
        @RequestParam @ApiParam(value = "", required = true) ZonedDateTime date) {
    System.out.println(date.toString());
    return new ResponseWrapper<String>(date.toString());
}
```

**So far I have tried:** 
creating a custom module and adding it as a @Bean in the configuration, adding the serializer and deserializer to the jackonBuilder object in configuration and something like the code in this [example](https://medium.com/@alexthered/how-to-register-a-custom-list-serializer-with-spring-boot-jackson-45f0d1ae3a27)

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? 
Each time I try I get the following error:

> "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.time.ZonedDateTime'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
>   @io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value
>   '2018-07-10T00:00:00+0000'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
>   [2018-07-10T00:00:00+0000]"

[image]

I am sending the following value each time: 2018-07-10T00:00:00+0000 and the value doesn't even reach the deserializer where I have my breakpoint.

Comment: You would have to provide factory method for `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`. I think that what is happening here is that when your @PostConstruct is executed, ObjectMapper is already craeted - but that is just an assumption.

Comment: Have you tried using a `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` instead? I find it much simpler for deserialization.

Comment: Spring-boot should automatically register your serializer and deserializer classes. Make sure they are in the auto-scan package hierarchy. Delete your JacksonConfiguration class - the spring provided injectable ObjectMapper will be configured for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I could not send ZonedDateTime in **GET** requests. Once I changed to **POST**, Spring was able to parse the date automatically.

I only added **spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust_dates_to_context_time_zone=true** so it takes the timezone into consideration.

If someone will want to send it in GET he will have to send a string and parse that instead of defining ZonedDateTime as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Add this bean in your configuration class:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureObjectMapper() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    final CustomZonedDateTimeSerializer serializer = new CustomZonedDateTimeSerializer();
    builder.serializers(serializer);

    final CustomZonedDateTimeDeserializer deserializer = new CustomZonedDateTimeDeserializer();
    builder.deserializers(deserializer);
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: this would work (and I tried that before) but my problem was that I used the wrong http method